# Why some tools such as dd don't need a mount point to work with a device?

Tags: mount, dd, disk

If I need to use a my USB drive on an Ubuntu machine I need to mount it first.
If my USB device is `/dev/sdb1` then I mount it with:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /home/some_folder
```

Then use `/home/some_folder` to read and write data to the USB drive.

But tools like `dd` can work directly with the device without a mounting point:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 ...
```

Why is that? Why can't I use my USB without mounting it but `dd` works fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use your USB without mounting it. You can use `dd` or other tools to copy data to it, and copy data from it. It is also common to use storage devices as swap space without mounting them.

"Mounting" means attaching a filesystem that resides on a separate storage device to a currently mounted filesystem. This requires a storage device that has been formatted with filesystem structures. After you have done this, you can access files and other objects on the mounted filesystem, without worrying on which device they reside. You just see one seamless filesystem tree. This is only possible when you mount that device.

Comment: bu I guess using `dd` to view my USB data it will just show me blobs of data, without much meaning or a file structure correct?

Comment: Yes. That's the point. You need software to interpret the filesystem structures on the storage device (if it contains filesystem structures). When you mount the filesystem, a kernel module such as `vfat` or `ext4` does that. However, even without knowing any filesystem structures, you can still use `dd` to make a bit-by-bit backup copy of the filesystem.